# Circular arc formula in terms of r in polar coordinates

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

I've been stuck with trying to write the arc length formula: $y=\ -\sqrt{g^2-\left(x-g\right)^2}+g$ in polar coordinates in terms of r with respect to theta.

I've been trying all sorts of instances of completing the square but I keep getting different powers of r without being able to factor and/or keep onto one side.

(A recent realization I've gotten was just possibly trying to factor out only x's and y's the substituting them with their polar analogs.)

Help!!!

edit: g is just a constant

Comment: What is $g$? I can't figure out what you are actually asking here.

Comment: g is a constant. Sorry I should I specified that.